# 2sxc Dnn.. Add existing content items to module

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a view of entities which are being displayed based on an entity type filter. I now need to reorder these and would like to use the built in 2sxc functionality to do this, so I have a created a new view of the data using the "module data source" so that the ordering will work.

But how do I now make all of the existing entities of the same type (definition) appear in this new view? The view now displays one item by default and I can replace that one item. But how do I add multiple existing items? I need the Entity ID's to remain the same for Query String usage and SEO.

Thanks, hope the question makes sense.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are asking "how can I add many items to an instance (module) manually, so that I can also sort them manually" - is this correct?

If yes, then you must make sure your template supports lists (checkbox in the template settings). This then gives you a [+] button; but you don't want to use that, as it would be for typing in new data. There's another button called "add an empty demo entry" which you'll see as a round (+) after pressing the more ... button once. Pressing this will give you empty entries, into which you can then replace existing items.