# Add existing content items to module. (without using demo)

Tags: 2sxc

My question is very much like [2sxc Dnn.. Add existing content items to module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050997/2sxc-dnn-add-existing-content-items-to-module)

However, I can only add a demo item once, and even if I could add more, it would be alot of work if the list of items is very long.

TL/DR:
How can I keep the sort options if I want to show all entities of a given type, and not only the ones I added for that specific view?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple. There are two modes which define what content is shown, one is the content-mode (which shows the items manually added) and the other is the data-mode, which treats items as data.

Basically if you want all-of-one-kind you can either create a visual Query which does exactly what you want, or just loop through App.Data["TypeName"] and show them.

See also https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/Razor-App#using-app-data-appdata

and http://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/12-differences-when-templating-data-instead-of-content